# Error C++ | ISO C++ forbids assignment of arrays

Tags: c++

I have a problem which I can not solve.
If this query is answered as "yes", then should anrede = female.

Dev++ gives me this error:
ISO C++ forbids assignment of arrays

---

```
char anrede[10];

printf("Anrede: female?? Yes/No");
scanf("%s", &anrede);

if(anrede == "Yes"){
    anrede = "female";
} else{
    anrede = "male";
}
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: use `std::string` and `std::cin`.

Comment: An array is a non modifiable lvalue. You cannot assign to it.

Comment: Look into strncmp and strncpy functions to see how to compare and copy strings; or as vlad says look at std::string etc

Comment: "female" wouldn't fit in a `char[5]` anyway. Use `std::string` ; it will expand to the size needed.

Comment: @user1059514: Did you read Vlad's comment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that your example is actually in C, trojanfoe's excellent answer might not suit you so well, in which case what you want is strcpy() and strcmp():

```
char anrede[7]; // increase to 7 to leave room for "female" plus the null byte

printf("Anrede: female?? Yes/No");
scanf("%6s", &anrede); // restrict read length to 6 chars + the null bute

if (strcmp(anrede, "Yes") == 0){
    strcpy(anrede, "female");
} else {
    strcpy(anrede, "male");
}
```

But you really don't want to be doing that if you can avoid it. strcpy() has no idea of buffer sizes, so it'll merrily run over the end of your target array and either corrupt your program's data or immediately crash. strncpy() is a nice alternative with a maximum length parameter, but it's not always available.

I'd go with the standard C++ solution trojanfoe posted, unless you actually do need to be writing in C (in which case, the question's incorrectly tagged).

Comment: It perhaps has to be mentioned that if the user inputs more than 6 characters, the program is entering undefined behaviour.

Comment: @Vlad, good point. scanf should be used carefully, see my edit

Comment: BTW this code can still crash - bonus internets for finding the error :)

Comment: @Kos:  &anrede in `scanf()` - it should be simply `anrede`.  Also `anrede` is not `NUL`-terminated explicitly.

Comment: @Matthew: are you sure you need `&` in `scanf` argument?

Comment: These comments, and my mistakes in my answer, just add weight to the argument that you really shouldn't do it this way if you can possibly avoid it.

Comment: @trojanfoe: you've beaten me :)

Answer (score 5):

Your code is C code, C is hard for beginners. C++ is simpler:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

std::string anrede;

cout << "Anrede: female?? Yes/No";
std::getline(cin, anrede);

if(anrede == "Yes"){
    anrede = "female";
} else{
    anrede = "male";
}
```

Comment: It doesn't answer his question. It is an alternative which is good, but understanding the problem is also required to be a good programmer!

Comment: @Nawaz: I don't see a problem in this since the question is tagged C++.

Comment: But it does NOT help him understanding the problem with **his** code. Also, using `char anrede[5]` is not forbidden in C++. Good programming is one thing, and C++ is another.

Comment: @Nawaz: It does, the problem is that 1) it's C code 2) the error message already says what's the problem. The question is "how to solve this".

Comment: That is not C either, as it would **not** compile even in C. Or if you mean just because he used `char[5]` it became C, then it is C++ also. The language doesn't forbid one from using it.

Comment: @Nawaz: I meant "C style". Don't be picky.

Comment: With that I agree. But you should also post some explanation. The error message is okay for those who understand it, not for newbies.